# Scanner.nextLine(); called before wanted due to loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a scanner `input` which is called by `getName()` in my `Player` class.

```
public static String getName()
{
  System.out.println("Enter your character's name.");
   String n = input.nextLine();
  return n;
}
```

However, when I use a loop in order to check for appropriate player input in my `RPG` class, everything works fine until I enter 
"n" or "N" for

```
System.out.println("Confirm Character (Y/N)");
confirm = input.next();
```

The way the loop works is that it calls the constructor `public Player(String cName, int cStamina, int cDefense, int cStrength, int cAgility, int cIntellect)` again if "n" or "N" are selected, however, because those two are String data types, and the constructor calls for a name first, it either recognizes the "n" or "N" as the name, or skips the whole name altogether. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class RPG 
{
  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static String confirm; 

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*\n{ ~ Pinnacle ~ }\n*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*");
    for (int s = 0; s < 1; s++)
    {

    Player me = new Player(Player.getName(), Player.getStam(), Player.getDef(),
    Player.getStr(), Player.getAgi(), Player.getInt()); 

      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
      {       
        System.out.println("*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*\n"+Player.name +
        "\nStamina: " + Player.stamina +
        "\nDefense: " + Player.defense +
        "\nStrength: " + Player.strength +
        "\nAgility: " + Player.agility +
        "\nIntellect: " + Player.intellect +
        "\n*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*");
        System.out.println("Confirm Character (Y/N)");
        confirm = input.next();
        if (confirm.equals("Y") || confirm.equals("y"))
          System.out.println("Character Created!");
        else if (confirm.equals("N") || confirm.equals("n"))
          s--;
        else
          i--;  
      }
  }
  }
}
```

Player Class below

```
import java.util.*;

public class Player extends Characters
{

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public Player(String cName, int cStamina, int cDefense, int cStrength, int cAgility, int cIntellect)
{


name = cName;
stamina = cStamina;
defense = cDefense;
strength = cStrength;
agility = cAgility;
intellect = cIntellect;
}
public static String getName()
{
System.out.println("Enter your character's name.");
String n = input.nextLine();
return n;
}
public static int getStam()
{
System.out.println("Enter your character's stamina.");
int s = input.nextInt();
return s;
}
public static int getDef()
{
System.out.println("Enter your character's defense.");
int d = input.nextInt();
return d;
}
public static int getStr()
{
System.out.println("Enter your character's strength.");
int st = input.nextInt();
return st;
}
public static int getAgi()
{
System.out.println("Enter your character's agility.");
int a = input.nextInt();
return a;
}
public static int getInt()
{
System.out.println("Enter your character's intellect.");
int i = input.nextInt();
return i;
}
public static void flee()
{

}

}
```

Here is a sample output with `Sample Name` as the first name input:

```
*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*
{ ~ Pinnacle ~ }
*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*
Enter your character's name.
Sample Name
Enter your character's stamina.
5
Enter your character's defense.
5
Enter your character's strength.
8
Enter your character's agility.
3
Enter your character's intellect.
2
*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*
Sample Name
Stamina: 5
Defense: 5
Strength: 8
Agility: 3
Intellect: 2
*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*
Confirm Character (Y/N)
n
Enter your character's name.
Enter your character's stamina.
2
Enter your character's defense.
3
Enter your character's strength.
6
Enter your character's agility.
4
Enter your character's intellect.
2
*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*

Stamina: 2
Defense: 3
Strength: 6
Agility: 4
Intellect: 2
*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*
Confirm Character (Y/N)
y
Character Created!
```

As you can see, the problems arise after `Confirm Character (Y/N)`.

Comment: you could use input.nextLine() instead of input.next()

Comment: @RafaelTeles changing `confirm = input.next();` to `confirm = input.nextLine();` does not resolve the issue, I'm afraid.

Comment: Could you post your "Player" class?

Comment: I'm interested in your getName() method. Where does it pull the name from? Or maybe something is going wrong with the call to it after the first call?

Comment: this is due to the fact that nextInt() does not move the scanner to the next line while nextLine() does. input your ints as following `int stamina = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());` and your code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out a solution for your problem, I'm not sure why your problem is happening. Instead of using `static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` in our Player class, create a new Scanner in every your gets*.

Here is a suggestion:

```
public static Player createPlayerFromConsole() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your character's name.");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your character's stamina.");
    int stamina = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your character's defense.");
    int defense = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your character's strength.");
    int strength = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your character's agility.");
    int agility = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your character's intellect.");
    int intellect = input.nextInt();

    return new Player(name, stamina, defense, strength, agility, intellect);
}
```

Comment: I was curious so I looked why this problem happened and found 2 posts that explain partially the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441444/java-nextline-skipped-in-runtime-while-working-previously